# I am getting error while i deploy my smart contract to ropsten test network(The same project successfully deploy on rinkeby test network)

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

[This  is the Project](https://github.com/rohitsahu21/Voting-Application/tree/master/Voting_App2)

I am getting error while i deploy my smart contract to ropsten test network(The same project successfully deploy on rinkeby test network)
it is the error

```
~/Voting-Application/Voting_App2$ truffle migrate -reset
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-core/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: To me it looks like you're deploying locally?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite some time googling for the same problem but eventually, every single time, the problem has been that my node has not been up-to-date and my account has had 0 balance.

So I recommend you make sure you are up to date and that your account has enough balance. If you have enough balance, try tweaking the gas settings in your `truffle.js` file. But don't set it also too high - different networks have different maximum values and I've noticed it's not always straightforward to find out the maximum value for each network.